# Is this an effective method of counting app’s registered users?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to count the registered users to my app using retrieving the data from Firebase, but I wonder if it's an effective method:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int usersCount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                textview.setText("We have " + usersCount + " registered users worldwide!"); //User Count
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you shared you're downloading all data under `users` to determine the count of the number of nodes.

If that is all you need from `/users`, it is wasting bandwidth. Say that each user node is 100 bytes, and you have 1,000 users, then you're downloading 100KB data, while you only need 4 bytes (`1000`). If all 1,000 users do that, you've download 10MB data to display 4KB of data. The wasted data applies to both your Firebase project, but also to each user's cell phone bandwidth usage.

But Firebase doesn't have anything equivalent to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users`, so with your current data structure there is no other way to determine the user count than to download the data.

---

If you want a less wasteful way to read the user count, you will need to store that user count in the database, and keep that updated with every write operation to `/users`.

Say that you keep the user count in a property `/user_count`. Then each time you add a user, you also need to increment `/user_count`, and each time you remove a user, you have to decrement `/user_count`. It is extra code, but once you've done that, you can

You can do this counting in your application code, but more common these days is to do it in Cloud Functions ([example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count)).

Comment: Thank you Frank, I’ll put it in a property on the database.

Answer (score 1):

Saving the user count in the SharedPrefs will only save the information locally on the device. This is correct and intended behavior. If you want to count the registered users, you have to store the number online on a server, like Firebase Firestore for example.

Comment: I noticed it. Actually, there is a way to avoid it with using Firebasedatabase listeners and get children count, but it isn't so effective.. Do you have maybe an idea - storing this data locally?

Comment: What do you mean by "effective". For sure getting information from the internet wont be as fast as reading the local storage but there is no other way to solve your problem than storing the number of registered people somewhere globally where it can be reached by other people

Comment: Can’t I use a static int counter? Every time a new user is added - it goes +1?

Comment: No you can't because the static in counter is stored in the RAM of the phone which is the same as writing to SharedPrefs, **you have to store the counter somewhere in the internet**

Comment: No you can't once the user clear your app data or uninstall the app all the data which was stored locally will be gone.

Comment: Thank you Max. I knew it, but I wanted to be 100% sure about that. I think it isn’t so necessary feature to the app, if there are like 10k users, it would take ~2 minutes to load it.

Comment: Why would it take 2 minutes to load if you just store the number 10.000 in a Firestore database?

Comment: You just increase the number by 1 every time a new user registers, no reason to count all users. You should probably stop what you are doing right now and learn some basics about programming and concepts